# Update created event in dialog

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'd like to update event which was created after selecting a time in calendar. I guess the event object is not passed to the dialog. How I can update new event and pass dialog variables to it ?

```
        select: function(start, end) {

            var $dialogContent = $("#event_edit_container");
            var titleField = $dialogContent.find("select[name='start']").val();

            var event = {title : 'xxx', start : start, end : end};
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', event, true);

             $dialogContent.dialog({
                modal: true,

                buttons: {
                save: function(event) {
                event.title = titleField;
                calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
                },}
            }).show();

            }
```

Included jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5JY3N/

Comment: Can you provide working jsFiddle?

Comment: @GeorgiNaumov http://jsfiddle.net/5JY3N/